# What is the best way to store gateway information on redhat system

Tags: linux, rhel, routing, route, gateway

I have herd 3 different ways to store gateway information on redhat system

1. /etc/sysconfig/network
2. /etc/sysconfig/static-routes
3. /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route- files

I am not aware of differences between above ways.
Help me to know differences and correct way

Answer (score 1):

According to the RHEL documentation the default gateway configuration is done through the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file.

[Configuring the Default Gateway](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes)

> The default gateway is determined by the network scripts which parse the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file first and then the network interface `ifcfg` files for interfaces that are “up”.

[`/etc/sysconfig/network`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/ch-sysconfig#s2-sysconfig-network):

> `GATEWAY=<value>`, where `<value>` is the IP address of the network's gateway.

Comment: is /etc/sysconfig/network is deprecated ?